# Dnsmasq - basic configuration

Tags: networking, dns, dnsmasq

I am trying run dnsmasq server in my local network for translating
name `www.mydomain.dev` to IP address `10.254.20.4`.

I need this name to correct signing SSL certificates.
I tried ping host from local machine on which I have installed dnsmasq and
from remote machine (my laptop) by command

```
ping mydomain.dev
```

but unfortunately it does not work.
Ping respond:

> "Ping request could not find host mydomain.dev. Please check the name and try again."

- In my laptop I have access to host by IP.
- In laptop I have set primary DNS as `10.254.20.4` and second DNS as `8.8.8.8`

In dnsmasq.config I have such configuration:

```
listen-address=127.0.0.1 

server=/dev/127.0.0.1

local=/localnet/

address=/www.mydomain.dev/10.254.20.4
```

What is wrong?
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for any help,

Michał

Comment: I think it's due to the config `listen-address=127.0.0.1 `. It means that it listens to loopback interface only.  I think you need to change it to listen to  the LAN's IP address of your "local machine". https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/dnsmasq#DNS_cache_setup

Answer (score 1):

`server` is a synonym for `local`

so your dnsmasq config would contain

```
listen-address=127.0.0.1 
local=/dev/
domain=dev
```

then open /etc/hosts and add

```
10.254.20.4  www.mydomain.dev
```

save and restart dnsmasq